# Fixed header/footer keep vertical scroll bar on top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a partly transparent fixed footer and header with scrolling content: https://jsfiddle.net/ru8jgxg9/

What changes to that JSFiddle would need to be made to keep the vertical scroll bar on top when there is overflow content (but keep the scroll bar the whole height of the window too)?

I notice stackoverflow.com seems to be able to do it:

[image]

[image]

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Fixed Header */
.dvTableTop {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
  border-color: #000000;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: Red;
  z-index: 1030;
}

/* Scrollable Content */
.dvContentContainer1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}


/* Fixed Footer */
.dvFooterContainer1 {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: Yellow;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fixed header and footer needs to be inside the scrolling container. Currently, they're outside the content container and will overlap it and its scrollbar.

Also, your content container can't have a `position: fixed`, otherwise it will fight with other fixed elements for position and cause overlaps. Fixed elements are always relative to the document, not the container.

Below is a working example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  font-family: arial, helvetica, san-serif;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, blue, red);
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="footer">Header</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am confused why you are doing it that way. All you have to do is remove your `position: fixed` from your `.dvContentContainer1` like so

```
.dvContentContainer1 {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

And as long as the content extends past the bottom of the page it will work the way you are wanting it to.

See this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ru8jgxg9/3/)

Edit: If you remove the `height: 100%;` from the body tag the scroll bar will go away if the content does not extend past the height of the screen.

See this [updated fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/ru8jgxg9/5/)

Comment: Nice thanks though the scrollbar does still appear without need when there are only 3 "abc"s as you mentioned.

Comment: Yep. Cool. Thanks